# What is wrong in these definitions in halt-mode

Tags: errors

I run

```
pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode -halt-on-error -file-line-error test.tex
```

which notices some errors in my file of the line 75

```
/Users/masi/Dropbox/bin/test.tex:75:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output
PDF file produced!
```

I do not get such an error while running the command without parameters.

**File where the line 75 is indicated**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, textcomp, mathtools, xparse}
\usepackage[T4, OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{/Users/masi/Dropbox/Physiology/images/}}
% Animations cannot be included here
% \addmediapath{ {/Users/masi/Dropbox/Physiology/animations/} }
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{multirow}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{media9} % animations swf
\usepackage{Tabbing}
\usepackage{doi, natbib}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
citecolor=blue,
allcolors=blue
}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{titling} % Two titles in one document
% \DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert} % This requires amsmath, I think


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Question and Answer %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{ans}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=yellow!20,
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=green!40,
    frametitlerule=true
}
\newcounter{question}[section]%
\setcounter{question}{0}

\newenvironment{question}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{question}%
    \begin{mdframed}[style=ans,frametitle={Question: #1}]
}{%
    \end{mdframed}%
}%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Smaller things

\newtheorem{case}{Case logic}
\mdfdefinestyle{que}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=cyan!20,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{case}

\newtheorem{sidenote}{Sidenote}
\mdfdefinestyle{que}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=cyan!20,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{sidenote}


\newtheorem{citation}{Citation}
\mdfdefinestyle{que}{                % TODO Line 75, refers to error here
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=yellow!20,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{citation}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%




\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newenvironment{definition}[1][Definition]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}] \emph}{\end{trivlist}}
\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{Keywords:} #1}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Counter Section %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
  \def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \refstepcounter{part}%
    \fi
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \LARGE \bfseries #2%
     \markboth{}{}\par}%
    \nobreak
    \vskip 3ex
    \@afterheading}
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



\begin{document}
Lorem ipsun.
\end{document}
```

**Can you see any mistakes in the line 75?**

Comment: You can't define an environment with the same name as an existing macro; so you can't define an `mbox` environment, because `\mbox` exists. The `\citation` command is used internally for, guess what, citations.

Comment: you _must_ also get the error in the case where you don't use the command line arguments

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding to David's answer, just to give reasons why the compiler stops at line 75 and not at line 74, which is the real cause.

First of all, `\citation` is a command used internally by LaTeX when writing in the `.aux` file a note about a citation made by `\cite`:

```
% latex.ltx, line 6118:
\let\citation\@gobble
```

It's defined to do nothing with its argument, because its purpose is to pass a message to BibTeX when it reads the `.aux` file.

Secondly, you can't define an environment `foo` if the command `\foo` already exists, because

```
\newenvironment{foo}{...}{...}
```

works by defining `\foo` and `\endfoo`. So your

```
\newtheorem{citation}{Citation}
```

will produce an error, because its working includes doing something equivalent to

```
\newenvironment{citation}
```

albeit in an internal form; actually, LaTeX does `\expandafter\ifdefinable\csname citation\endcsname`, which accounts for the error message. However it does so *after* having looked for a `[` (the possible trailing optional argument).

This causes the compiler to eat up spaces until finding the first token that's not `[` or stopping at `[` if it finds one. Thus TeX will have gone to line 75 during this search for tokens. An end of line is like a space, in this case.

There's not much one can do about this. The line number in the error message can only be the one active when TeX realized there's an error and this comes after the lookup, when eventually starting to process `\newtheorem` (actually `\@ynthm`, but it's mostly irrelevant).

Moral of the story: the line number can help, but the error message is the most informative part.

The error message would have shown line 74 if the input had been

```
\newtheorem{citation}{Citation}\relax
```

because `\relax` stops the lookup for `[`. Should you add `\relax` after each `\newtheorem` statement? No, just look at the error message, if it happens, which in this case is

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \citation already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

that indeed shows the real problem.

Answer (score 7):

running your MWE shows an error on that line,

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \citation already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.75 \mdfdefinestyle
                    {que}{                % TODO Line 75, refers to error here
?
```

presumably you have the same error in the log?

so really it's the line before

```
 \newtheorem{citation}{Citation}
```

declaring a `citation` environment which is already defined in this context.